# R data.table: summarise values of several rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R which looks like this one:

```
   code gruppe proz_grouped
1:    1      2    14.751689
2:    2      2    22.063523
3:    3      2    35.441111
4:    4      2    27.743676
5:    1      3     7.575869
6:    2      3    23.420090
7:    3      3    38.513576
8:    4      3    30.490465
```

Is there an easy, elegant way to get the sum of *proz_grouped* for the codes (*code*) 3 and 4 by group *gruppe*?
The result should look sth. like this:

```
   code gruppe proz_grouped
1:    1      2    14.751689
2:    2      2    22.063523
3:    NA     2    63.18471
5:    1      3     7.575869
6:    2      3    23.420090
7:    NA     3    69.0035
```

Since code cannot be summarized, I would expect an NA for the code column.

Thanks

Comment: use `dput` to produce code for reproducible example, get more points to your question, get more people involved into answering, get more answers

Answer (score 2):

We can use `recode` to change the values and then do the group by `sum`

```
library(data.table)
library(car)
df1[, code := recode(code, "c(3,4)=NA")
        ][, list(proz_grouped = sum(proz_grouped)), .(code, gruppe)]
#  code gruppe proz_grouped
#1:    1      2    14.751689
#2:    2      2    22.063523
#3:   NA      2    63.184787
#4:    1      3     7.575869
#5:    2      3    23.420090
#6:   NA      3    69.004041
```

Or use `%in%` to change 3, 4 into NA, group by 'code', 'gruppe' and get the `sum` of 'proz_grouped'

```
 df1[code %in% 3:4, code := NA][,
       .(proz_grouped = sum(proz_grouped)) ,.(code, gruppe)]
```

Comment: or a small hack with ifelse provided the value OP wants to aggregate are over `2` : `setDT(y)[,code:=ifelse(code>2, NA, code)][, .(res=sum(proz_grouped)), .(gruppe, code)]`

Comment: The data.table way to modify would be `DT[code > 2, code := NA]`. It's not clear that the OP actually wants the code variable edited, though; to me, it looks like they just want it temporarily for this summarization.

Comment: @eddi You are right, but I copied it as a data.frame and convert to `data.table`.  Forgot to take the `setDT` part

Comment: @akrun fwiw `fread` now handles this kind of input (after removing the row numbers), so no need to do `read.table` and then convert

Comment: gotcha + I just realized that `read.table` takes cares of the row names

Answer (score 2):

```
dt[, .(proz_grouped = sum(proz_grouped))
   , by = .(code = replace(code, code > 2, NA), gruppe)]
#   code gruppe proz_grouped
#1:    1      2    14.751689
#2:    2      2    22.063523
#3:   NA      2    63.184787
#4:    1      3     7.575869
#5:    2      3    23.420090
#6:   NA      3    69.004041
```